# Trying to interpret allocations in Allocation Tracker

Tags: android, memory-management, android-studio

I am currently trying to observe the allocations in the allocation tracker tab of the Android Debug Monitor.

The largest allocation is "getRecentAllocations". Is this just from me clicking the "Get Allocations" button? I am tyring to figure out why this is so large? Is this anything to do with my app, or is it just from me pressing the button?

Thank you[image: Screenshot of allocation tracker]